# How I divide 64 x 64 pixel image into 3 × 3 overlapping regions (with an overlapping size of 14 pixels)

Tags: image-processing, lbph-algorithm

[image: This is point where I am facing difficult]How I divide 64 x 64 pixel image into 3 × 3 overlapping regions (with an 
   overlapping size of 14 pixels) using python

Comment: or any image how we divide M x N overlapping region

Comment: It can be done in ImageMagick. In fact I have a bash unix shell script that does that called overlapcrop. See http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.php. You could call that from Python using subprocess call. But you can do it more directly with 9 crops using ImageMagick crop function. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop. In Python, you can use Wand (based upon ImageMagick) or PIL (Pillow) or Numpy to make 9 crops of the image.

Comment: Huh? I'm going to guess that you want the cropped images to be square? But I have no idea how long the sides will be. Could you kindly clarify please?

Comment: @MarkSetchell now, can you recognise my problem?

Comment: Any news/updates?

Answer (score 2):

Mmmm... let's agree that the problem is the same vertically as it is horizontally so if we can solve the horizontal division into squares we can apply the same technique vertically, ok?

Now let's look across the page left-to-right. We have a square 64 pixels wide and we want to divide it into three with overlap - let's make those three squares red, green and blue:

[image]

Let's look at the central green square. It will have `o` overlapping pixels on the left, `o` overlapping pixels on the right and `u` pixels unique to the green square in the middle.

[image]

The red and blue squares have the same size, so they will be the same. So that means, if you run across the top of the coloured diagram, you will get:

```
o + u + o + u + o + u + o = 64
```

i.e.:

```
4o + 3u = 64
```

We know, `o` is 14, so:

```
4*14 + 3u = 64

u = 8/3
```

So your squares all need to be:

```
14 + 8/3 + 14 = 30.66
```

I don't know how to make a square image measuring 30.66px by 30.66px.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like ImageMagick is what you are looking for. There are wrappers for it for most languages. It has a set of CLI tools, too. A good starting point is their [CLI documentation](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php) and their [forum](https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewforum.php?f=1).

PythonMagic wraps the [Magick++ C++ library](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/Documentation.html).